# Targetwidth and Targetheight of cordova camera plugin

Tags: cordova, camera

I'm using Cordova Camera plugin in my hybrid mobile app. I want to scale down the image to 350px wide. I thought I can do that by just passing only `targetWidth` as 350. But from the documentation it looks like I've to pass both `targetWidth` and `targetHeight`. Can somebody explain why I've to pass both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked into the source code and they handle the cases where no `targetWidth` and no `targetHeight` was specified or it's 0.

So don't pass it, or if you have problems because you didn't pass it, then pass 0.

The images keep the aspect ratio, so if you pass 100 height and 100 width, and the original image is 200 x 400 you will get a 50 x 100 image, if you pass just the width you will get a 100 x 200 image

Comment: If I just pass width as 100 then also I should get 100 x 50 not 200 x 100 correct?

Comment: sorry you specified height x width, i thought the reverse.

Comment: We ran into an issue of it failing if not both parameters are passed on an iPhone. Don't pass in the parameter with caution.

Comment: More details on the iphone issue on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823195/ionic-cordova-ios-ignores-targetheight

Comment: Because of the 'fitting' behaviour passing a large value for the one you don't care about (width or height) will also work okay.