# targetWidth and targetHeigth cordova camera plugin bug

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an app that utilizes the Cordova camera plugin. When I use the tablet's camera to take a picture, the resolution is 3096x4128.

However, when I use the app and set the targetWidth and targetHeight to 1920 and 1080, respectively, the resulting picture resolution is only 810x1080.

Is the Cordova plugin performing additional compression or something else that is causing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The cordova documentation is very weak in this regard - however it does say the aspect ratio is respected. This means it keeps the aspect ratio of the original image - basically it scales it to fit inside the width/height that you request without cropping or deforming the image.

In your case as the cameras shape is higher than it is wide and your target is wider than it is high to 'fit' it in it has to make it much smaller to it inside your height.

These two questions on SO are relevant:

- [About how this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163575/targetwidth-and-targetheight-of-cordova-camera-plugin)
- [Some issues with ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823195/ionic-cordova-ios-ignores-targetheight)